# Metodo post y put no funcionan en postman Laravel

Tags: laravel, postman

cuando intento enviar una solicitud de post para guardar nuevos registros o una solicitud de put para modificar algun registro ya creado, postman no realiza ninguna de las operaciones, la operacion de index y de show si funcionan.

Tengo el siguiente metodo de store en mi controlador de user:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $reglas = [
        'name' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required|email|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required|min:6|confirmed'
    ];

    $this->validate($request, $reglas);

    $campos = $request->all();
    $campos['password'] = bcrypt($request->password);
    $campos['verified'] = User::USUARIO_NO_VERIFICADO;
    $campos['verification_token'] = User::generarVerificationToken();
    $campos['admin'] = User::USUARIO_REGULAR;

    $usuario = User::create($campos);

    return $this->showOne($usuario, 201);
}
```

Tengo el siguiente metodo de update en mi controlador de user:

```
public function update(Request $request, User $user)
    {
        $reglas = [
            'email' => 'email|unique:users,email,' . $user->id,
            'password' => 'min:6|confirmed',
            'admin' => 'in:' . User::USUARIO_ADMINISTRADOR . ',' . User::USUARIO_REGULAR,
        ];

        $this->validate($request, $reglas);

        if ($request->has('name')) {
            $user->name = $request->name;
        }

        if ($request->has('email') && $user->email != $request->email) {
            $user->verified = User::USUARIO_NO_VERIFICADO;
            $user->verification_token = User::generarVerificationToken();
            $user->email = $request->email;
        }

        if ($request->has('password')) {
            $user->password = bcrypt($request->password);
        }

        if ($request->has('admin')) {
            $this->allowedAdminAction();
        
            if (!$user->esVerificado()) {
                return $this->errorResponse('Unicamente los usuarios verificados pueden cambiar su valor de administrador', 409);
            }

            $user->admin = $request->admin;
        }

        if (!$user->isDirty()) {
            return $this->errorResponse('Se debe especificar al menos un valor diferente para actualizar', 422);
        }

        $user->save();

        return $this->showOne($user);
    }
```

este es el modelo de User:

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    //use Notifiable, HasApiTokens, SoftDeletes;

    const USUARIO_VERIFICADO = '1';
    const USUARIO_NO_VERIFICADO = '0';

    const USUARIO_ADMINISTRADOR = 'true';
    const USUARIO_REGULAR = 'false';

    public $transformer = UserTransformer::class;

    protected $table = 'users';
    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'email',
        'password',
        'verified',
        'verification_token',
        'admin',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token',
        'verification_token',
    ];

    public function setNameAttribute($valor)
    {
        $this->attributes['name'] = strtolower($valor);
    }

    public function getNameAttribute($valor)
    {
        return ucwords($valor);
    }

    public function setEmailAttribute($valor)
    {
        $this->attributes['email'] = strtolower($valor);
    }

    public function esVerificado()
    {
        return $this->verified == User::USUARIO_VERIFICADO;
    }

    public function esAdministrador()
    {
        return $this->admin == User::USUARIO_ADMINISTRADOR;
    }

    public static function generarVerificationToken()
    {
        return Str::random(40);
    }
}
```

esto es lo que me muestra postman tras enviarla solicitud post:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

esto es lo que me muestra postman tras enviarla solicitud put:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Te está devolviendo html, poné en Visualize (en vez de Pretty) para ver la página. ¿qué es lo que no funciona? ¿te dá algún error?

Comment: si, me esta devolviendo html, en vez de la respuesta del nuevo registro, en json, que deberia ser el recientemente creado, errores no me aparecen, en visualize me aparece 'Can't visualize the response',

Comment: Pero devuelves un json desde el controlador? Que es `$this->showOne($user)`?

Comment: supuestamente es el usuario que acabo de crear enviandole los parametros, pero no lo ingresa en la base de datos

Comment: O sea, es otra función en el controlador... Pero que devuelve? Una vista? Un json? Pusiste para ver que dice el html en postman? La imágenes que subiste no sirven porque no se ve que dice ese html, solo se vé la primer parte. Y que no guarde en la base de datos puede ser la validación o algún error en el código, tienes que mostrar lo que te responde laravel para que podamos ayudarte.

Comment: Te vuelvo a explicar, en postman cuando hago el envio de datos atravez del metodo post, debe primero ingresar los datos que envio en la base de datos y despues devolvermelos con un formato json, pero como puedes ver en la parte de abajo del pretty en vez de devolverme el json me devuelve HTML, que es el HTML de la pagina de welcome de laravel